# How can i reload the multiselect from Jquery?

Tags: jquery, refresh, reload

`enter code here`hi I want to reload the multiselect after an ajax event. I tried this :

```
$("#addCategoryButton").click(function(){
    category = $("#addCategory").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/contributii/addCategory/",
        data: { addCategory: category }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {

        $("#categorySelect").multiselect("refresh");
    });
});
```

but it doesnt work. What can i do ?
this is where i called the multiselect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#categorySelect").multiselect({  // multiselect
        header: false
    });
});
```

Comment: How is the multiselect loaded the first time?

Comment: is there someone to help me ?